# Two SELECT inside NOT IN echo array() mysql php, one SELECT IS OK

Tags: php, mysql

my code is OK only if I remove one (SELECT) inside the NOT IN, if I add two (SELECT) inside the NOT IN, it echo array(); First, I want to get the fruit that val=those value and mark = 'major'. Then I want to remove any of those fruit that either the mark='age' or mark='ripe', so I used OR fruit NOT IN. I already check the SELECT inside the NOT IN, it is OK when they are alone.

```html
<?php
$dia = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("
   SELECT fruit FROM table WHERE val IN (%s,%s,%s) AND mark = 'major' OR fruit NOT IN (
(SELECT fruit FROM table WHERE cat='uncommon' AND val = %s AND mark='age'), 
(SELECT fruit FROM table WHERE cat='uncommon' AND val = %s AND mark='ripe')) GROUP BY fruit
   ",$sym1,$sym2,$sym3,$age,$ripe));



?>
```

Comment: you're mixing `and` and `or` in the main query without `()` to enforce their parse/execution order.

Comment: how to enforce them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need two queries for this, you just need to alter your conditions.  Change:

```
(SELECT fruit FROM table WHERE cat='uncommon' AND val = %s AND mark='age')
```

To:

```
(SELECT fruit FROM table WHERE cat='uncommon' AND (val = %s AND mark='age') OR (val = %s AND mark='ripe'))
```

Otherwise you'd need an aggregate query.

Comment: I have to separate them, because I have two different values to equal the val, it's $age and $ripe

Comment: Ok, so I'll change it around.